# iText embedded ttf font not visible in Adobe Reader

Tags: pdf, itext, acrobat, truetype, adobe-reader

I'm stamping an existing PDF file with extra information using the iText library.
The extra information is text that should be rendered in a custom TTF font.

Problem is that the text is not visible in the Adobe Reader only.
Other PDF viewers, such as the default eVince reader in Ubuntu and the Google online PDF reader render the stamped text in the custom embedded font just fine.

I tried multiple encodings, such as Cp1251, BaseFont.Identity_H, ...

The code where the magic happens:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(inputPdf));
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream("stamped.pdf"));
PdfContentByte canvas = pdfStamper.getOverContent(1);
String text = "The stamp";
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("assign.ttf", "Cp1251",BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
canvas.beginText();
canvas.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLUE);
canvas.setFontAndSize(bf, 13);
canvas.moveText(310, 600);
canvas.showText(text);
pdfStamper.close();
```

Comment: When you go to Document > Properties and open the Fonts tab, what do you see? Do you see the font?

Comment: I see the problem: you're probably using an obsolete version of iText!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a syntax problem. Text state in PDF is marked with `BT` and `ET`. These operators are added using the `beginText()` and `endText()` methods. You have a `BT`, but no `ET`. Adobe Reader is more strict than the other viewers (that's why I prefer Adobe Reader over all other viewers: people should respect the syntax when writing code).

Add the following line before `pdfStamper.close();`

```
canvas.endText();
```

Better yet, read my [book](http://itextpdf.com/book) and you'll find out you can reduce the complexity of your code by using `ColumnText.showTextAligned()`.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, the end marker solved the issue on Adobe Reader.
Also kudos for the awesome iText library.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer: it made me gain a 2000+ reputation ;-)